# Any package is not installing in my machine after downloading java. Give solution for my Problem

Tags: java

I tried to install java. Immediately after download i just quite the terminal.
Happening that i'm unable to install any thing. My machine giving the following information. What i've to do?

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sun-java6-jdk : Depends: sun-java6-bin (>= 6.26-1natty1) but it is not going to be installed
 sun-java6-jre : Depends: sun-java6-bin (>= 6.26-1natty1) but it is not going to be installed or
                          ia32-sun-java6-bin (>= 6.26-1natty1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: gsfonts-x11 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `apt-get -f install` from the command line as the message suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to do what it says:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

from `man apt-get`:

> **-f, --fix-broken**
>              Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any
>   packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are
>   specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The option is
>   sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT itself
>   does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a system. It is
>   possible that a system's dependency structure can be so corrupt as to
>   require manual intervention (which usually means using dselect(1) or
>   dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending packages). Use of
>   this option together with -m may produce an error in some situations.